# Exibir informações no HTML com angular

Tags: php, html, angularjs, json

Olá, pessoa, sou iniciante em angular, javascript e etc. Estou tentando exibir as informações de um json retornado por um script php, mas estou tendo este erro:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed

Angular:

```
angular.module("moduloJogos", []);
angular.module("moduloJogos").controller("moduloJogosCTRL", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('jogos.php').then(function(response) {
    $scope.partidas = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
```

HTML. Tabela que exibe:

```
<tbody ng-controller="moduloJogosCTRL">

  <tr ng-repeat="partida in partidas">
    <td class="timeCasa">{{partida.timeCasa}}</td>
    <td class="tdAposta"><input type="button" class="btn" id="{{casa + partida.idPartida + partida.cotTimeC}}" value="{{partida.cotTimeC}}"/></td>
    <td class="tdAposta"><input type="button" class="btn" id="{{empate + partida.idPartida + partida.cotEmp}}" value="{{partida.cotEmp}}"/></td>
    <td class="tdAposta"><input type="button" class="btn" id="{{fora + partida.idPartida + partida.cotTimeF}}" value="{{partida.cotTimeF}}"/></td>
    <td>{{partida.timeFora}}</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

PHP que pega as informações e monta o json:

```
$partidasTotais = "[";

while($jogos = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  $timeCasa = $jogos['time_casa'];
  $timeFora = $jogos['time_fora'];
  $idMatch = $jogos['id_jogo'];


  $content = $chamaURL->retornaConteudo('https://api.soccerama.pro/v1.2/odds/match/'.$idMatch.'?api_token='.$apiTOKEN);
  $cotCasa = $content["data"]["0"]["types"]["data"]["0"]["odds"]["data"]["0"]["value"];
  $cotEmp = $content["data"]["0"]["types"]["data"]["0"]["odds"]["data"]["2"]["value"];
  $cotFora = $content["data"]["0"]["types"]["data"]["0"]["odds"]["data"]["1"]["value"];

  $partidaIndividual = '{"timeCasa":'. $timeCasa.',"timeFora":'. $timeFora.',"idPartida":'. $idMatch.',"cotTimeC":'. $cotCasa.',"cotEmp":'. $cotEmp.',"cotTimeF":'. $cotFora.'},';

$partidasTotais .= $partidaIndividual;


}

$partidasTotais .= "]";

echo json_encode($partidasTotais);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso geralmente acontece quando tu não tem um ID único para o ng-repeat, tu podes, segundo a [documentaçã](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)o, usar `track by $index` que vai fazer com que a posição dentro do array se torne o ID e te recomendo também verificar se não possui elementos *undefined* dentro do teu `$scope.partidas`.

Faz umas alterações:

- Coloca `$i = 0;` antes do while;
- Altera teu código de atribuição da seguinte forma:

  ```
  if($i == 0) $partidaIndividual = '{"timeCasa":"'. $timeCasa.'","timeFora":"'. $timeFora.'","idPartida":"'. $idMatch.'","cotTimeC":"'. $cotCasa.'","cotEmp":"'. $cotEmp.'","cotTimeF":"'. $cotFora.'"}';
  else $partidaIndividual = ', {"timeCasa":"'. $timeCasa.'","timeFora":"'. $timeFora.'","idPartida":"'. $idMatch.'","cotTimeC":"'. $cotCasa.'","cotEmp":"'. $cotEmp.'","cotTimeF":"'. $cotFora.'"}';
  ```
- No final da iteração coloca o `$i++;`
- Os Colchetes são necessários não remova-os.

Comment: Pode me explicar o que seria o $index? Porque eu tentei colocar exatamente assim "partida in partidas track by $index" e ele me mostrou muitas linhas (além do que o script php retorna) e todas vazias. Já o $scope.partidas está certinho...

Comment: Quando tu faz `console.log($scope.partidas);` ele retorna um **Array** de **Objetos**? Olha esse exemplo:  `ng-repeat="value in [4,4]"` ele causaria o mesmo erro que tu tem, pois não tem um Key único, usando o track by $index ele usaria a posição dentro do Array (0 e 1) como Key.

Comment: Ele retorna algo assim: `"[{\"timeCasa\":Hamilton Academical,\"timeFora\":Kilmarnock,\"idPartida\":688005,\"cotTimeC\":2.15,\"cotEmp\":3.30,\"cotTimeF\":3.35},{\"timeCasa\":Aberdeen,\"timeFora\":Partick Thistle,\"idPartida\":688009,\"cotTimeC\":1.53,\"cotEmp\":4.05,\"cotTimeF\":6.05},]"`

Comment: Esse teu Json tá muito inválido, tenta remover o `json_encode` e vê o que ele retorna.

Comment: tirei o json_encode e ele deu erro **Unexpected token H in JSON**. Removi o colchete do inicio e do final do json e ele retornou certo, porém com o `track by $index`, na tela aparece um número enorme de linhas vazias novamente.

Comment: Me manda como está o JSON agora

Comment: `{"timeCasa": Hamilton Academical,"timeFora": Kilmarnock,"idPartida": 688005,"cotTimeC": 2.15,"cotEmp": 3.30,"cotTimeF": 3.35},{"timeCasa": Aberdeen,"timeFora": Partick Thistle,"idPartida": 688009,"cotTimeC": 1.53,"cotEmp": 4.05,"cotTimeF": 6.05},{"timeCasa": Rangers,"timeFora": Ross County,"idPartida": 689806,"cotTimeC": 1.44,"cotEmp": 4.60,"cotTimeF": 6.55},{"timeCasa": Inverness CT,"timeFora": Dundee,"idPartida": 689809,"cotTimeC": 2.05,"cotEmp": 3.30,"cotTimeF": 3.65},{"timeCasa": Motherwell,"timeFora": Hearts,"idPartida": 689814,"cotTimeC": 3.80,"cotEmp": 3.70,"cotTimeF": 1.87},`

Comment: teu JSON precisa ficar assim: [ 0 => {"timeCasa": Hamilton Academical,"timeFora": Kilmarnock,"idPartida": 688005,"cotTimeC": 2.15,"cotEmp": 3.30,"cotTimeF": 3.35}, 1 => {... }];

Comment: Aeee, funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Krint estamos aqui pra fortalecer a comunidade, então fico feliz de ajudar :)